# Can I bring a sex toy in checked-in luggage travelling to Mauritius but transiting in Dubai?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, dubai, sex

I'm travelling from Europe soon and I'd like to know if it is authorised to bring a sex toy and lube with me in my checked-in luggage transiting through Dubai. I haven't found much research about transiting passengers. Although, I know it is illegal to bring sex toys in the country, but I'm only stopping in Dubai for a couple hours and my luggage will be already checked-in from France to arrive at my destination. I was just wondering if it is safe to transit in Dubai without being stopped or the sex toy being confiscated

Comment: You've checked whether they're legal in Mauritius, haven't you?

Comment: Yes, it's illegal to sell sex toys on the island but there must have been tourists who have gone there with their toys. I've been searching and I've found one or two people who said that they brought their toys to Mauritius on their holiday

Comment: Many people have learned the hard way that transiting in Dubai with illegal things never ends well, do not take that risk however small it is

Answer (score 7):

A good rule of thumb is this:  if you will be clearing Customs and Immigration for the airport through which you are transiting, you will be subject to their laws of what may be imported and what you may not.  If you are not required to clear Customs and Immigration, then legally you have not been admitted into the country and you are probably in better shape with this situation.

For example, transiting through the US (e.g. Toronto Pearson-Atlanta-Cape Town) you clear US Customs even though you are only in the US for a connection.

Also, consider if you have a flight cancellation or weather problems.  You may have to clear customs in Dubai even if you didn't intend to actually do more than make a connection there.

Personally, I wouldn't risk bringing things that are illegal in Dubai in either circumstance.  If you really want to take the toy, rebook your flight to route only through airports where such materials are legal.

Comment: I do not have to go through immigration, I'm just transiting but I do understand it is quite a risk. I'm also questionning if I'll get through to Mauritius because it's illegal to sell toys on the Island despite people who have bought them online and there must have been multiple tourists who have brought their own

Comment: @C.Jackson If sex toys are important for your vacation satisfaction, I suggest destinations like Canada or Australia where they're legal :)